# Updating a table instead of Insert Into

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am selecting data from a table and inserting it into another if the data in that table does not exist.

```
DECLARE @EmployeeNumber NVARCHAR(100)
SET @EmployeeNumber = 'Emp001'
IF EXISTS(SELECT E.EmployeeNumber FROM [databaseOne].[dbo].[Employee] E WHERE E.EmployeeNumber =    @EmployeeNumber)
BEGIN
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT UT.EmployeeNumber FROM UserTable UT WHERE UT.EmployeeNumber = @EmployeeNumber)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO UserTable(EmployeeNumber, Surname)
    SELECT E.EmployeeNumber, E.Surname FROM [databaseOne].[dbo].[Employee] E
    WHERE E.EmployeeNumber = @EmployeeNumber
END
ELSE
  BEGIN
      --Update
  END
END
```

if the data does however exist I just want to update the existing data.

How can Update as opposed to INSERT INTO.

Kind regards

Comment: Take a look at the [MERGE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) statement, it's used to conditionally delete, insert or update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `Merge` funcion.

Your query will look somewhat like this:

```
MERGE UserTable AS Target
USING (SELECT E.EmployeeNumber, E.Surname FROM [databaseOne].[dbo].[Employee] E 
       WHERE EmployeeNumber = @EmployeeNumber) AS Source
ON Target.EmployeeNumber = Source.EmployeeNumber
WHEN MATHCED THEN 
     UPDATE SET Target.Surname = Source.Surname
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
     INSERT (EmployeeNumber, Surname) VALUES (Source.EmployeeNumber,Source.Surname);
```

Refer [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625(v=sql.100).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Try something along the lines of:

```
UPDATE UserTable
SET
EmployeeNumber=E.EmployeeNumber
Surname=E.Surname
FROM UserTable
INNER JOIN [databaseOne].[dbo].[Employee] AS E
ON (E.EmployeeNumber = UserTable.EmployeeNumber )
WHERE UserTable.EmployeeNumber = @EmployeeNumber
```